# How to force arrowkey right to be pressed.in JAVA using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I try to get data from different pages and wounder how to solve so right arrow key are pressed. (right arrow key on keyboard)

For example this page (https://www.bettingexpert.com/user/profile/TheLightLord).
If I press right arrow key on the keyboard then it shows me the next bet.

But when I try driver.findElement(By.xpath("anything")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT); nothing happens.

I have tried both xpath and className (of course with something else then anything) but have not succeed.
How do I solve this? Is it possible?

In my setup I have the dom.webdriver.enabled set to false. Does this has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could work but maybe you could use the java robot class

```
import java.awt.Robot;

robot = new Robot();
robot.setAutoDelay(250);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
```

Read [this](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/robot-class-keyboard-events/) for further explanation.